# Why is it called Sensitivity/Recall and Specificity?

Tags: classification, precision-recall, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity

Where do the terms: Sensitivity, Recall and Specificity come from historically? I've been looking for an answer for quite some time but to no avail.

I understand the formulae and what they mean but I keep mixing up the terms and I think understanding the intuition/history behind them would help me remember them.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the story about the princess and the pea?

Comment: I already like this. Yes..?

Comment: Her sensitive skin could detect a pea under all of the padding!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the terms originated in the field of psychology. Recall is about recollection of relevant information.